# How can I connect my php code to MySQL database?

Tags: sql, database, database-connection

How can I connect my php code to MySQL database?

I have tried many times and it cannot access the database.

These are the codes in my php file:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Brandon's Search Engine - Results</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Brandon's Search Engine</h2>
<form action='./search.php' method='get'>
<input type='text' name='k' size='80' value='<?php echo $_GET['k']; ?>' />
<input type='submit' value='Search' >
</form>

<hr />
<?php
$k = $_GET['k'];

$terms = explode(" ", $k);
$query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE ";

foreach ($terms as $each){
$i++;
if ($i == 1)
$query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
else
$query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
}

// connect
mysql_connect("sql102.freezoy.com", "frzoy_13854016", "xxxx");
mysql_select_db("frzoy_13854016_search");

$query = mysql_query($query);
$numrows = $query->num_rows;
if ($numrows > 0){

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$id = $row('id');
$title = $row('title');
$description = $row('description');
$keywords = $row('keywords');
$link = $row('link');

echo "<h2><a href='$link'>$title</a></h2>
$description<br /><br />";

}

}
else
echo"No results found for \"<b>$k</b>\"";
// disconnect
mysql_close();
?>

</body>

</html>
```

I have insert some data into the database.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error are you receiving? Did you try to look at `mysqli_connect_error()`?

Comment: In addition, if your php version is greater than 5.0 (I think that is the version anyway) you should be using [mysqli_connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php).

Comment: My phpMyAdmin version is 3.5.8.2

Comment: It is deprecated from 5.5, and will be removed in the future.

In this case, it would help to diagnose to know at which stage your code is failing. Can you record the responses of the mysql db connections?

You can see how to do this here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: How can I record it? I still don't understand

Comment: Your phpmyadmin version is not the same as your php version, although that suggests you're using 5.2: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php

Comment: OK you want to add in a response like this:

`<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>`

Comment: You will also need to check if database user, you are using is accesible from outside or through the hostname. Check the port to connect too. For Grating priviledges to a user, you can check this guide. http://www.31bit.com/technology/86-mysql-database/302-how-to-grant-remote-access-to-a-mysql-database

Comment: How can I update my phpmyadmin? I have downloaded the file.